# How to Set Page Break using NPOI in C#?

Tags: c#, excel, npoi

Is there any way to set the page break in EXCEL file using NPOI in C#..?

I have follow the solution on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16656388/npoi-page-breaks), but still nothing happend on my generated excel files.
I'm using NPOI 2.0.1.0.

Comment: maybe this might work for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16656388/npoi-page-breaks

Comment: Please include your code showing how you have attempted to do this yourself

Answer (score 2):

```
var doc = new XWPFDocument();
var pageBreak = doc.CreateParagraph();
var pageBreakRun = pageBreak.CreateRun();
pageBreakRun.AddBreak(BreakType.PAGE);
```